# How can I get Excel to show me if the same values are appearing, even though they are not in the same order

Tags: excel, duplicates, formula

Basically what I have is a 3 columns of data with a 4th that is a CONCENTATE of the three columns, however, the data repeats sometimes in a diffeent order and i need to either highlight or show with a 0 or 1 if the same values have been repeated in a different order, the image attached shows what I would want to happen

[image]

Can Anyone help as i'm banging my head on the desk here

Comment: Critical question: Will the component identified with 3 letters always appear in the third column? Might it also appear in one of the others?

Comment: What if there are duplicates but they are in the **same** order?  Do you want those also highlighted, or excluded?

Comment: Another thing we don't know is whether a string can repeat in the same row. It's a bit late now I know, but if it can't then it would make it an easier question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have O365 with the `SORT` function, you can set up a helper column:

```
=CONCAT(SORT(A1:C1,,,TRUE))
```

Then use conditional formatting to check for duplicates.

If you don't have the `SORT` function, you can try:

```
=CONCAT(INDEX(A1:C1,N(IF(1,COUNTIF(A1:C1,"<" & A1:C1)+1))))
```

and if you don't have the `CONCAT` function, try:

```
=INDEX(A1:C1, INDEX(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"<"&A1:C1)+1,1)) & INDEX(A1:C1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"<"&A1:C1)+1,2))&INDEX(A1:C1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"<"&A1:C1)+1,3))
```

Comment: Perfect! I see what you did now :)

Thank you very much!